# How do i pass the ForEach array index through a NavigationLink in to another ForEach without it crashing?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I have this odd issue where it will work if i wait two seconds and press the NavigationLink but if i try to press it earlier than that it will crash the app, i am not sure what i am doing wrong. All i want to do is to get the array index from the first ForEach to use it for another ForEach loop.

In the first struct i have declared these

```
@ObservedObject var vm = TripViewModel()
```

with the loop looking like this. I made sure to check with both print and a Text in the label that it actually get the array index, which it does.

```
                    ForEach(vm.TripData.indices, id: \.self) { trip in
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: TripView(tripCount: trip),
                        label: {
                            TableRow()
                            Text("\(trip)")
                        }
                    )
                    
                }
```

And in the second struct, it has these declared

```
  @ObservedObject var vm = TripViewModel()
    var tripCount: Int = 0
```

with the ForEach relying on the previous loops index.

```
ForEach(vm.TripData[tripCount].Leg, id: \.self) { day in
```

It is right here that i get the crash error "**Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range**"

Comment: how you declare `TripData ` inside `TripViewModel`

Comment: TripData is a @Published property wrapper in the ViewModel. It will pull the first array in my json decodable.

`@Published var TripData = [TravelDetail]()`

Comment: `leg` array of `int` ?

Comment: Leg is an array of dictionaries. Here is how the JSON looks like https://pastebin.com/h4H0jLza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially `TripData` has a count = 0 and you try to access it's first zero index element which doesn't exist at that time hence the crash , you need to change it to

```
ForEach(vm.TripData.isEmpty ? [] : vm.TripData[tripCount].Leg, id: \.self) { day in
```